# How can I optimise animation on the canvas in my custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am working on a custom view where I would like to display a single post from Facebook in a custom View, it would include the name of the person who made the post, the updated time, the message itself or post content and the handle that lets a person expand or collapse the post with a 'Read More' or 'Read Less' depending on how big the post is. 
The code for my Custom View looks like this http://pastebin.com/VkxpfLnj , and my animation class looks like this http://pastebin.com/HsEadatY
The problem with the message part is it can be very huge and hence I need an expand or collapse handle. I create a new StaticLayout object everytime the text changes.

I took 3 approaches to animation

1. based on the difference in the number of pixels, suppose my post was 300 pixels tall before expanding and after expanding was 700 pixels tall, I would simply animate between these two, the problem is that I have to call requestLayout each time and it results in 40 calls per expansion or contraction
2. The other approach I tried out was to animate based on the number of lines , if there were 4 lines before expansion and 8 lines after expansion,I would simply increment the height of the postview by line height * (final number of lines - initial number of lines )* interpolated time, this approach gave me a just 10 requestLayout() calls but laggy animation.
3. As per my ViewUtils animation method, my current approach calls requestLayout only at the beginning, the center and end of the animation and results in roughly 12 requestLayout() calls per expand or collapse.

   How can I use the static layout or for that matter draw multiple lines on canvas in such a way that I can fade in text when I expand or collapse and at the same time keep the number of requestLayout() calls to a minimum. I would also like to make this Canvas support LTR and RTL if possible. Any suggestions?